# Unable to insert data into mysql from website front end using XAMPP

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I am a beginner for basically everything in the field of coding.
I was trying to insert values into MySQL database using php code. Snippet provided bellow.

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","") or die("error");
$db_select = mysqli_select_db($conn,"wayout") or die("error");
$res =mysqli_query($conn,$sql) or die("error");
```

Then this error appeared:

> mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in C:\Xampp\htdocs\add-building.php on line 93
> error

This is my user found in PHP:

```
User name   Host name   Password    Global privileges   User group  Grant
root            localhost     No         ALL PRIVILEGES                  Yes
```

Please do help me figure why it is not connecting and how to solve it.

Comment: It looks like you are using some really bad tutorial. I highly encourage you to find something better. If you are only starting to learn PHP then you should learn PDO instead of mysqli. PDO is much easier and more suitable for beginners. Start here https://phpdelusions.net/pdo & https://websitebeaver.com/php-pdo-prepared-statements-to-prevent-sql-injection. Here are some good video tutorials https://youtu.be/2eebptXfEvw & https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sVbEyFZKgqk&list=PLr3d3QYzkw2xabQRUpcZ_IBk9W50M9pe-

Comment: `PDO is much easier and more suitable` for every one i'd say.